# Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>'

Tags: node.js, file

For some reason, I get the error "Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream'" in TypeScript.

Code:

```
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Fizzify/dotfiles/main/wallpaper.jpg")
    .then(
      (res: Response) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const dest = fs.createWriteStream("./Doom.png");
          res.body!.pipe(dest);
          res.body!.on("end", () => resolve("it worked"));
          dest.on("error", reject);
        })
    )
    .then(() => console.log("Done downloading!"));
```

I tried using the other pipe methods like pipeThrough or pipeTo but no joy.

I expect it to be downloading the image and using pipe on the downloaded image.

I tried using https instead of fetch but also no joy as it only downloads a 0kb image which is empty.

Comment: The fetch `res.body` object does not have a `.pipe()` method.  It is a certain type of readableStream (not a nodejs stream).  You can see its methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream.  Remember, the `fetch()` interface was developed for the browser, not for nodejs.

Comment: FYI, see [this article](https://2ality.com/2022/06/web-streams-nodejs.html#support-for-web-streams-in-node.js) for how to convert a web stream from `fetch()` to a nodejs stream.